# How to take only frist name from long listing name with dots in between using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have existing python file which is working as expected.

with below CODE 1, i able to return the required values,

example: I have folder name called google_com_uk (I have the multiple folder like google_com_usa, google_com_de ), with CODE 1 i able take the **com** as a return  value.

CODE 1

```
def services_list(root, details):
dir = root + details
list = glob.glob("%s/google_*" %(dir))
no_prefix = {x.replace(f"{dir}/google_", "") for x in list}
no_suffix = {re.sub('_.*$', '', x) for x in no_prefix}
return no_suffix
```

with CODE 2, I want to achieve same but here folder names are different

example: I have folder name called uk.google.com (I have the multiple folder like usa.google.com, de.google.com), with CODE 2 i want to take the return value as a uk, nothing else!

CODE 2 - Modified as this but not able to get the required return value.

```
def services_list(root, details):
    dir = root + details
    list = glob.glob("%s/*.google.com" %(dir))
    no_prefix = {x.replace(f"{dir}/*.google.com", "") for x in list}
    no_suffix = {re.sub('_.*$', '', x) for x in no_prefix}
    return no_suffix
```

Comment: you need to change the regular expression to match `.` instead of `_`. Don't forget that you have to escape `.` to match it literally.

Comment: `.replace` doesn't allow wildcards, so the `*` given to it in code 2 and code 3 is interpreted as a literal `*`. You could perhaps use `re.sub` to generate `no_prefix` as well as `no_suffix`?

Comment: @slothrop i have tried with re.sub to generate no_prefix as well as no_suffix? but not succeed

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `re.search` instead of removing prefix and suffix. This way you can define a regex to extract the specific part that you want.

Here is my proposal:

CODE 1

```py
import glob
import re


def services_list(root, details):
    dir = root + details
    list = glob.glob("%s/google_*" % (dir))

    response = set()
    for el in list:
        result = re.search(r"\/google_(\w+)_(\w+)", el)

        if result is None:
            raise Exception(f"Unrecognized pattern: {el}")

        response.add(result.group(1))

    return response
```

The same applies to the other code, but the pattern changes:

CODE 2

```py
import glob
import re


def services_list(root, details):
    dir = root + details
    list = glob.glob("%s/google_*" % (dir))

    response = set()
    for el in list:
        result = re.search(r"\/(\w+)\.google\.(\w+)", el)

        if result is None:
            raise Exception(f"Unrecognized pattern: {el}")

        response.add(result.group(1))

    return response
```

Note: I also suggest NOT to use dir and list variable names because they are built-in classes